# Is it possible to run DNSCrypt server on myself?

Tags: dns

OpenDNS introduced DNSCrypt, and they runs the server in their OpenDNS server.

http://www.opendns.com/technology/dnscrypt/

And the client program is opensourced:

https://github.com/opendns/dnscrypt-proxy

This is significant for network environment that is censorship-ed, like China.

But OpenDNS servers are quite slow responsive to China, I hope to setup a DNSCrypt server on my own server, but can find nothing like that.

Does anyone know about if the DNSCrypt server part opensource or not ?

Comment: You can as well run a normal VPN tunnel to your DNS server, (route there only DNS traffic, if you wish).

Comment: Where your _server_ will be located ? Outside of China ?

Comment: this is not programming related

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment / experience I'd like to share: I was in CN last week, behind, inside, and before the great firewall. But both VPN nor SSH tunneling work that great. DNSCrypt neither, but it's the least worst option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many other servers are supporting the protocol, and it is easy to add it to your own server as well.

See the [DNSCrypt implementations](https://dnscrypt.info/implementations) section of the documentation for some information.

Most of the servers, if not all, use [encrypted-dns-server](https://github.com/jedisct1/encrypted-dns-server), either directly or via the [DNSCrypt docker image](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-server-docker).

The dnscrypt-proxy client also includes step by step instructions to [install a dnscrypt server on a VPS](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/How-to-setup-your-own-DNSCrypt-server-in-less-than-10-minutes).

Another option is PowerDNS [dnsdist](http://dnsdist.org/).